# call function after .shift()

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an array of functions.

```
var wrapFunction = function(fn, context, params) {
    return function() {
          fn.apply(context, params);
    };
}

var sayStuff = function(str) {
     //do work & return something
    return str;
}

var fun1 = wrapFunction(sayStuff, this, ["Hello, world!"]);

que = []
que.push(fun1);
```

Right now I'm doing this:

```
var current = que.shift()
current();
```

This works fine, but is there a way to call que.shift & run all the functions all the way down to my `sayStuff` function; so that 
`current === 'Hello, world!'`

I tried `(que.shift())();` but it doesn't trigger the whole cycle.

Comment: Your code does not work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(que.shift())();` should work if you `return` the value of your `fn.apply` call:

`return fn.apply(context, params);`

Answer (score 1):

You should add `return` in the anonymous function:

```
var wrapFunction = function(fn, context, params) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(context, params); // <-- Insert return here
  };
};
```

Then,

```
que.shift()(); // "Hello, world!"
```